# How to load my own code into Laravel? Differences between those ways?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm kind of confused on how to load my own code (classes or just regular functions) into a Laravel app. I've seen this done in several ways:

1. Creating a folder inside the app directory (for example: `app/libs`) and add `app_path().'/libs'` to `start/global.php`
2. Add it into `composer.json`'s `"require"`
3. Add `"psr-0"` into `composer.json`'s `"autoload"` and add there the files
4. Add a `My\Custom\Service\Provider` into `app/config/app.php`'s `'providers'` and the alias for the facade

What's the difference between them? Why and when should I use any of those ways? Should I load a class, several .php files or simply the folder? Maybe reference those 3 things at the same time?

### EDIT:

These are my guesses:

- Option 2 is just for packages
- Option 3 if you want to load every class inside a custom namespace declared within the new created folder (don't get why the `"psr-0"` instead of just adding it to `"classmap"`)
- Option 1 is the same as option 3, just handled by Laravel instead of Composer
- You can reference a folder and it will load every class found inside, or you can reference a certain file and it will load the class found inside

About option 4:

- If you want to use the facade anywhere on your code, and that will need the namespace added into composer.json

### EDIT 2:

- If you add them to `"classmap"`:

  ```
  "classmap": [
      "app/libs"
  ]
  ```

  every class from any namespace within files inside the `app/libs` folder, will be loaded
- If you add them to `"psr-0"`:

  ```
  "psr-0": {
      "Libs": "app/"
  }
  ```

  it will load every class within the `Libs` namespace inside the `app/libs` folder

Still not sure why/when to use service providers and aliases.

### EDIT 3:

`"psr-0"` if I want to load a namespace that follows a folder structure (it won't load a class within a subnamespace if it doesn't match the folder structure)

`"classmap"` for "random" classes, functions... sort of "the rest"

Comment: It really depends on _what_ is your own code: classes or functions or packages are not the same thing, you can use all of the above according to what you're trying to load

Comment: edited main post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can load your own code 2 (maybe 3) ways in laravel.

1. use composer
2. use ClassLoader
3. Manual include or require anywhere

> Option 2 is just for packages

yes, you're right.

> Option 1 is the same as option 3, just handled by Laravel instead of
>   Composer

yes, you're right.

> Option 3 if you want to load every class inside a custom namespace
>   declared within the new created folder (don't get why the "psr-0"
>   instead of just adding it to "classmap")

some packages or classes adhere psr-0 standard, the rest is not. psr-0 option is mapping namespace to directory. the classmap is mapping
the namespace to certain directory or file and used for the class that is not adhere psr-0 standard.

[You can use the classmap generation support to define autoloading for all libraries that do not follow PSR-0/4.](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap)

> If you want to use the facade anywhere on your code, and that will
>   need the namespace added into composer.json

nope, instead, you have to add class alias for the facade in `app/config/app.php`

1. if your code is just file, not a class, then use composer autoload `files`
2. if your code is class but not adhere psr-0/4 standard, use composer autoload `classmap` or just add the containing directory to `app/start/global.php`.
3. otherwise, use composer autoload `psr-0` or `psr-4`.

Comment: gotcha, i'll use psr-0 if i wanna load a namespace that follows a folder structure (it won't load a class within a subnamespace if it doesnt match the folder structure) and classmap for "random" classes, functions... sort of "the rest"

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 4,I add all of my class in "mylibrary" folder.

Then at **app/start/global.php** , I add **app_path().'/mylibrary',**

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/mylibrary',
));
```

Within mylibrary there is MyClass.php , within MyClass.php there is test_myfunction()

and at app/view/home.blade.php I add these code :

```
<?php
  $FMyClass11 = new MyClass;
  $just_test=($FMyClass1->test_myfunction());
?>
```

Hope it works for you. :)